# Flash file(swf) is not running after downloading

Tags: flash

This is the link of the .swf file
http://www.greguide.com/Free-GRE-Practice-Tests/GreGuide-Numeric-Entry-PT-1.swf
It is working correctly in the server. But after downloading it is not working. It shows like the image added. Is there any way to download this type of swf by editing code or any other way?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swf mentioned in your question is trying to load a text file ("rightblock.txt") and because it didn't find it, it shows you the loading text message.

So, to avoid that and get the swf working, you have to create that text file and put it in the same directory as the swf, you can let it empty or if you want that swf loads the right block (which contains the message "hi all, ... learn more"), you have to download the right block swf, which is "sample1.swf", from the same site, and put its name in the text file, to get at final one of these two situations :

- GreGuide-Numeric-Entry-PT-1.swf + rightblock.txt (empty).
- GreGuide-Numeric-Entry-PT-1.swf + rightblock.txt (contains the text : "sample1.swf") + sample1.swf.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are absolutely correct. Could you please tell me how you discovered it?  NB: I am technical and very strong on c#.

Comment: @user1712287 Using the browser developer tools, you can see that your swf is loading the text file which contains the swf file name. Also, when using a flash player debug version, you can see the ioerror because swf cant' load the text file.